# object is not subscriptable using lambda x and def()

Tags: python-3.x, function, pandas, lambda

From a pandas.dataFrame.describe() command the following values are taken:

```
XS = min(Angl.loc['min'])
XMM = Angl.loc['25%'][0]
XM = Angl.loc['mean'][0]
XMP = Angl.loc['75%'][0]
XL = max(Angl.loc['max'])
x = [XS,XMM,XM,XMP,XL]
```

With those values I want to use a formula to get y.

I did a lamba function like:

```
y = lambda x : 1 + (-1/(x[2]-x[0]))*(x - x[0])
y(0.8)
```

also I tried:

```
def mu(x):
    y = 1.0 + (-1.0/(x[2]-x[0]))(x - x[0])
    return y
```

but in both I have the following error:

```
      1 def mu(x):
      2     #y = 1.0 - 1.0/(x[2]-x[0])*(x - x[0])
----> 3     y = 1.0 + (-1.0/(x[2]-x[0]))(x - x[0])
      4     return y
      5 print(mu(0.8))
```

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

If I use the values in the same formula with a print() function, no problem was found.

```
print(1.0 + (-1.0/(x[2]-x[0]))*(0.8 - x[0]))
0.311117357138
```

Any help?

UPDATE:
I change to:

```
def f(x):
    y_ = lambda x : 1 + (-1/(XMM-XM))*(x - XM)
    y = y_(x)
    return y
```

And the problem was solved.

Comment: you should tag this with a language

Comment: You seem to be trying to use the name `x` for two entirely different things - a global list, and the parameter to your function.  That's obviously not going to work.